# Belkin Realtek chipsets

Tags: wireless-networking

What is the right (read as WORKS) driver for:

Ubuntu 14.04

Belkin F9L1001 v1

USB Vendor ID 050d 945a

Is it r8712u  or  rtl8192su or rtl8192 something?

Further, if either is supposed to work or nobody knows, why does the r8712u driver start giving me such problems with WPA2 Personal Authentication, Association request to the driver failed, authentication timed out, possibly related to EAPOL.  Is there a newer version of a) driver b) wpa_supplicant c) some config setting like EAPOL-version =2 ?!? ?!?

Answer (score 0):

My interim solution is to use:

NDISWrapper to Belkin Windows 2000 driver
and

**Important**
Be sure to background the WPA_Supplicant command with -B.  Otherwise it negotiates keys but then tries to re-negotiate, fails, and requests to disconnect.

The Verbose debug output at that time is "not in suitable state for new pre-authentication"